# Binding SelectedItem subclass list to a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox, selecteditem

I want to display a list of joined strings to a textbox. I use converter for that which works great. The problem is when I try to bind the selected item sub class to a textbox, it doesn't display the values. It displays Projectname.Model.Tag

Tags is the subclass

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="23" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Tags,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto"/>
```

If I do this

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="23" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Tags.Name,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto"/>
```

It just displays empty

How do I properly bind the selected item to a textbox?

**EDIT** 
So I have a class Book which contains a list of Tags. Name is the property of Tags.

```
public class Book:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private int _idBook;
        private string _title;
        private ObservableCollection<Tag> _tag;

        public int IdBook
        {
            get { return _idBook; }
            set { _idBook = value; }
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value; }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Tag> Tags
        {
            get { return _tag; }
            set { _tag = value; OnPropertyChanged("Tags"); }
            }
}
```

And Tag model

```
 public class Tag:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private int _idTag;
        private string _name;

        public int IdTag
        {
            get { return _idTag; }
            set { _idTag = value; OnPropertyChanged("IdTag"); }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
        }
}
```

Comment: Not enough info. What is `Tags`, and what is `Name`?

Comment: I will add more info

Comment: Be careful calling things "subclass" that are not actually a sub class. A subclass is a convention of class inheritance and not what you're talking about. In this case, Tags is a property of Book, not a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the answer was in the converter rather than using string.Join I'm using String Builders Append and now it binds properly.